# OpenCV error -215:Assertion Failed, can't figure out how to diagnose this error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, bots, pynput

I've been following a tutorial for developing a template matching bot for the flash game Burrito Bison, [github with code linked here](https://github.com/flakas/burrito-bison-bot) but even with the original source code can't seem to get the bot to run.  The error appears to be with the line `res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_grayscale, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)` in the file `vision.py`

The full error is `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:589: error: (-215:Assertion failed) corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function 'cv::crossCorr'`

Haven't tried much, I've never worked with OpenCV before and this is quite new to me.

```
def match_template(self, img_grayscale, template, threshold=0.9):
    """ Matches template image in a target grayscaled image """

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_grayscale, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    matches = np.where(res >= threshold)
```

Expected result is it working properly and playing the game.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cvMatchTemplate() function giving assertion failed error? opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083625/cvmatchtemplate-function-giving-assertion-failed-error-opencv)